# Git bash pull,fetch and clone not working

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git and git bash. I've set an ssh key for my account and password, but I can't pull or clone any repository from my GitHub.

When I enter any of above mentioned commands I have no response, like my git hub ignores everything. I'll upload two screenshots of git bash. Entering pull and clone commands and responses I get.

Git clone commad and result

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Git pull command and result

[image]

I've probably messed something up with server configuration, but I can't figure it out.

All answers and comments are welcome.

EDIT: answer.

Here is screenshot of results of `git config --list` and `git config --list --global` commands.

[image]

Comment: Could you please do a `ping www.github.com` to see if you can connect to it? Also, could you show us your git configuration with `git config --list --global`? (you can hide your personal config information, like `user.email` or `user.name`.

Comment: I've pinged it and got reply.

Comment: @Wikiti And I've replaced screenshot of clone command with config commands so you can see.

Comment: Since you have "PinocchioInterface" folder in master branch, is it possible that commands work, but you just have output redirected somewhere? Do you get the files from the repo?

Comment: When I clone the repo on a random location, I don't get any file downloaded. Same story with pull, nothing happens.

Comment: how do you have "PinocchioInterface" repo then? Was that before the installation?

Comment: Everything worked fine until I've added ssh authentication and configured TortoiseGit so that I don't need to type password every time I want to pull/push. Something called Pageant.

Comment: You seem to have remote url using https protocol, but push url using git protocol (as well as puttykeyfile). That's probably not what you really want.

Comment: Do not post images of text, instead copy-and-paste the actual text directly into your post. Images of text are not easily parsable, searchable, or accessible.

Comment: you could try `git clone --progress` with your cloning, maybe it will display more output, as then it should print out the progress despite of terminal settings.

Comment: Should I change the pushing url to https protocol or the other way around? Change the remote url using git protocol? Whats the better solution?

Comment: I would recommend removing the separate push url conf and try then. If you want to choose, https is a bit more reliable (one reason: corporate networks not blocking it) but less efficient/secure.

Comment: I've changed it from TortoiseGit, and still it is not working. Will reinstalling Git and TortoiseGit help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling TortoiseGit and reinstalling Git solved the problem. Thank you everyone for help!

Answer (score 0):

First things first: `clone`.

You can clone either with SSH or HTTPS.

```
git clone https://github.com/thatuser/thatrepo.git
git clone git@github.com:thatuser/thatrepo.git
```

SSH relies on keys and things, so it's probably easier to get going with HTTPS.

Cloning will automatically try to add the url that you clone from as a git `remote` for that directory.

Then `cd` into that repo that you've clone and run `git remote -v` to make sure that you've got the url listed as a remote (probably `origin`).

Once you've got the repository's directory cloned and have ensured that you've got a `remote` listed (and I'll assume it's `origin`), then you can go ahead and try a pull.

```
git pull origin master
```

is the safest bet, since you may not have defaults configured telling git to assume the default remote name "origin" or default branch name "master".

Comment: Git clone is not working either. Only status I get is : Cloning into '<RepositoryName>'... and then process stops.